# Saving a really simple tensorFlow model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am in the process of creating a really simple tensor flow network as part of a Django/ React native web app, I have managed to create a training set which works and produces the following output when run with plt:

[Training output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GcQm.png)

However, as im a total noob when it comes to neural networks and Tensor Flow im finding saving this trained set challenging, I have tried saving using saver() and had a look at session but neither has really worked so far. What I want is to save this trained model so that i can use it in my application to match User entered questions(represented by integers) and pre-set answers. Also, I'm aware that the data is super basic and can easily be done by hardcoding the responses, this project is more about learning rather than getting reults in the most effecient way possible. Any feedback is really appreciated, source code listed below!

## machine_learn.py

```
def loss(self, predicted_y, desired_y):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(predicted_y - desired_y))    

def train(self, model, inputs, outputs, learning_rate):
    with tf.GradientTape() as t:
        current_loss = self.loss(model(inputs), outputs)

    dQ = t.gradient(current_loss, model.Q)
    model.Q.assign_sub(learning_rate * dQ)

def train_network(self, value_set):
    model = TrainingModel(value_set)
    desired_list = [4.00, 3.00, 2.00, 1.00]
    num_examples = 10000
    desired_ans = desired_list[0]
    inputs = tf.random_normal(shape=[num_examples])
    Qs = []
    epochs = range(150)
    for _ in epochs:
        Qs.append(model.Q.numpy())
        current_loss = self.loss(model.Q, desired_list)
        self.train(model, inputs, desired_list, 0.1)
        print(current_loss)
    plt.plot(epochs, Qs, 'r')
    plt.plot([desired_ans] * len(epochs), 'r--')
    plt.legend(['Q', 'true q'])

    plt.show()
```

## training_model.py

```
class TrainingModel(object):

def __init__(self, questions):
    self.questions = questions
    self.Q = tfe.Variable(questions)

def __call__(self, inputs):
    return self.Q
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.
  Unfortunately, "Neither has really worked so far" is not a problem specification.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial resource.

Comment: In short, since there's no apparent attempt to save and restore the model here, we have no way of fixing your problem.  You can search for the appropriate tutorials as well as we can, but those apparently haven't given you what you need.  Give us the MCVE -- for starters, include your save attempt and get rid of the overhead, such as plotting.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Prune's comments but as a fellow noobie who's had a lot of trouble finding a useful tutorial for saver() take a look at the example programs here:
[Useful example code](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/).

The save and restore code should be what you're looking for.  I'd also encourage you to check out the tensorboard examples, it will show you how to graph variables without having to use the plt library.  Hope this helps!